# Standby Testing for the Paper-based General GRE?

Tags: gre

I have been trying out various GRE practice tests and find myself doing better on the paper-based test due to the ability to mark up, underline, and circle the text. My quantitative stays the same for both tests (170), but I see around a 6 point difference on average for the verbal section.

Unfortunately, the only paper-based testing center neat me in Canada is full. My only opportunity of getting the paper GRE done this year is to go on standby there on February 1 and see if I will be accepted. What are the chances that they will let me in if I show up an hour an a half early?

Comment: You have to ask them, actually. There will possibly be a few no-shows, but also a number of hopeful drop-ins. If it isn't a long drive, you could try it. But be prepared for disappointment, also.

Comment: Any centres in America that tou could get to? May be easier as you are not crossing any borders...

Comment: @buffy Who do I ask? I called GRE Help and that was a terrible and long-drawn experience that got me nowhere and I called the graduate department of the college that hosts the test and they said that I should call GRE because they have no affiliation with the test.

Comment: @SolarMike Unfortunately, the paper general GRE is not available in the U.S.; I’m lucky that I live in MN!

Comment: I won't do the standby if I were you. The stress that you'll endure while waiting to get into the test will have some impact on the score. You may want to think about this before you go.

Comment: I don't think they can let you in with all the payments and security stuff. They might have to reserve the empty seat for the first few minutes as well.

Answer (score 1):

No one here can answer this for you. However there's nothing lost on going except a bit of your time and money. If those 6 points are worth it to you, go and go quite early.